# PyGTK: Connecting menu item with FileChooserButton

Tags: python, dialog, gtk, pygtk, filechooser

I'd like to connect a menu item with a `FileChooserButton`, such as when the user clicks the menu item, it will be 'as-if' the `FileChooserButton` was clicked.

Tried to do it by emitting some signal inside the `FileChooserButton` when the menu item is activated, but couldn't find any relevant signal.

Found something interesting in the [GTK Source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/plain/gtk/gtkfilechooser.c?h=gtk-2-24), line 2835:

```
/* Button */
static void
button_clicked_cb (GtkButton *real_button,
        gpointer   user_data)
{
  open_dialog (user_data);
}
```

and line 455:

```
/* Button */
priv->button = gtk_button_new ();
g_signal_connect (priv->button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (button_clicked_cb),
        button);
```

But it looks like something internal (`priv` = private?); I couldn't emit that signal neither call that function.

Any ideas how can I achieve that?  (beside splitting the `FileChooserButton` to a simple `button` and an independent `FileChooser` dialog)

Comment: The code you are looking at is how the button itself responds to it being clicked. The `open_dialog()` function is a private function, yes.

Comment: You can try `gtk_widget_activate()`, at least (that's what Company told me in IRC, anyway). If it fails it will return `FALSE`. (Look up the respective names for Python.)

Comment: It's just `activate()` - and sadly, it returns False.

Comment: My only other suggestion then is to share GtkFileChooserDialogs. When you create the GtkFileChooserButton, set the `dialog` property. (You must do this while creating the button; the property is construct-only.) Not sure if this does work, but it's worth a shot...